# Grouping is very slow on PostgreSQL even with index

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have Log table with 94M records in it and hosting on 16GB of RAM, 6CPU, and fast SSD.

The Log table has several fields but the query is run using three main fields, UserId(int), DateStamp(timestamp), and Result(boolean).

These fields also have one index

```
create index "IX_Log_UserId_DateStampDate_Result"
    on "Log" ("""UserId""", ("DateStamp"::date), """Result""");
```

We are casting DateStamp to Date in the index because we are grouping DateStamp as Date.

SQL

```
SELECT "Log"."UserId",
       date("Log"."DateStamp") AS "Date",
       count(*)                AS "Conversions",
       "Log"."Result"
FROM "Log"
GROUP BY "Log"."UserId", (date("Log"."DateStamp")), "Log"."Result"
```

Execution Plan (it looks likes that the index is not used in a grouping. )

```
Group  (cost=16701795.29..17867897.49 rows=93288176 width=9)
"  Group Key: ""UserId"", (date(""DateStamp"")), ""Result"""
  ->  Sort  (cost=16701795.29..16935015.73 rows=93288176 width=9)
"        Sort Key: ""UserId"", (date(""DateStamp"")), ""Result"""
"        ->  Seq Scan on ""Log""  (cost=0.00..3100034.20 rows=93288176 width=9)"
```

The problem is that executing a grouping query takes about 4minutes, we have been running the same DB on MS SQL before migrating to PostgreSQL, and MS SQL doing that query in just 10 seconds on the same PC.

Other PostgreSQL params

```
work_mem=32000kb (changing this do not makes any difference)
shared_buffers=200MB
effective_cache_size=12GB
```

EDITED

I am also adding an extended explain plan.

```
GroupAggregate  (cost=16701795.29..19033999.69 rows=93288176 width=17) (actual time=278258.047..516820.577 rows=331187 loops=1)
  Group Key: ""UserId"", (date(""DateStamp"")), ""Result""
  Buffers: shared hit=31437 read=1902506, temp read=216860 written=217003
  I/O Timings: read=9319.798
  ->  Sort  (cost=16701795.29..16935015.73 rows=93288176 width=9) (actual time=278258.028..403513.564 rows=93288174 loops=1)
        Sort Key: ""UserId"", (date(""DateStamp"")), ""Result"""
        Sort Method: external merge  Disk: 1734880kB
        Buffers: shared hit=31437 read=1902506, temp read=216860 written=217003
        I/O Timings: read=9319.798
        ->  Seq Scan on ""Log""  (cost=0.00..3100034.20 rows=93288176 width=9) (actual time=0.021..137339.749 rows=93288174 loops=1)
              Buffers: shared hit=31426 read=1902506
              I/O Timings: read=9319.798
Planning Time: 0.700 ms
Execution Time: 517321.399 ms
```

Comment: Not that it matters, but is there any reason why you don't just drop the `GROUP BY` clause and do a `SELECT DISTINCT ...` instead?

Comment: @Tim Biegeleisen I am not sure what you mean, but grouping and distinct are two different things. I need to group by Dates, UserId, and Result(true or false).

Comment: Try comparing the execution plans to see what SQL Server does differently. Perhaps SQL Server's query optimizer realized this is a "DISTINCT" and avoided grouping? Perhaps it parallelized the query? Something else? SQL Server puts emphasis in manageability and auto-tuning for 30 years. PostgreSQL on relational features. There's always going to be a difference (try taking a real backup of a single database instead of the entire cluster).

Comment: ...they are identical in this case

Comment: @Tomas in the query you posted you're actually doing a `DISTINCT`. There are no aggregations, so the results will only contain a single row per group values. The same thing `DISTINCT` does. A `DISTINCT` only needs a single SORT though, not grouping, so it's a lot cheaper

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen: the only difference is that Postgres can use a parallel plan for the GROUIP BY, but not for the distinct.

Comment: @Tomas SQL Server's query optimizer is pretty smart and actually simplifies queries before generating an execution plan. If SORT+GROUP get replaced by just a SORT, the execution plan *and* memory usage will be a lot cheaper

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name but in this query, all that's needed is a SORT because this is essentially a DISTINCT. We need to see both execution plans and "borrow" some tricks from SQL Server

Comment: Sorry, guys, I have forgot to add a `count(*)` to the query, that's why I am using `GROUP BY` instead of `DISTINCT`. Edited the question. The execution plan remains the same.

Comment: You should really get rid of those dreaded quoted identifiers. Including double quotes in the name (`""UserId""`) is even worse

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I have added an extended explain plan.

Comment: You are limited by the sort step which is done on disk. This can only be "fixed" by either increasing `work_mem` substantially or by trying to find a way avoid the sort. Which Postgres version are you using? Am a bit surprised that it's not using a parallel plan.

Comment: We are using 12 versions.  Changing work_mem does not improve query speed significantly, even setting it to 1GB which we do not want.

Comment: @jjanes timestamp, my bad.

Comment: It is not possible to have the indicated index on that table, as the column names do not match.  `"""UserId"""` is different than `"UserId"`.  Unless the table has columns with both spellings, then it should be obvious why the index doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I am checked your explain analyze result. But your DB use full table scan but not index scan, maybe your index is incorrect or your index does not match your group by fields.

Please view my code:

```
create index "IX_person_mobile_main_mobile_id_date"
    on person_mobile_main (mobile_id, (insert_date::date)); 

explain (analyze, buffers, format text)   
select mobile_id, insert_date::date, count(*) from examples.person_mobile_main
group by mobile_id, insert_date::date;
```

Result:

```
GroupAggregate  (cost=0.42..70002.48 rows=547265 width=16) (actual time=0.165..683.103 rows=547265 loops=1)
  Group Key: mobile_id, (insert_date)::date
  Buffers: shared hit=513538 read=1498
  ->  Index Scan using "IX_person_mobile_main_mobile_id_date" on person_mobile_main  (cost=0.42..59057.18 rows=547265 width=8) (actual time=0.141..424.740 rows=547265 loops=1)
        Buffers: shared hit=513538 read=1498
Planning Time: 0.250 ms
Execution Time: 718.435 ms
```

In my result shown `Index Scan using "IX_person_mobile_main_mobile_id_date"`
But in your result shown `Seq Scan on "Log"`. You do have not an `Index Scan` keyword.

Comment: Maybe because the table has millions of records and the query planner decides not to use index.

Comment: It is not possible that the query planner does not use indexing for millions of records. Instead, the index is needed for millions, billions of records

Comment: @Tomas I can repeat his finding even with millions of rows.

Comment: @RaminFaracov This is more than possible https://thoughtbot.com/blog/why-postgres-wont-always-use-an-index Also you can find dozen of articles about that at google https://www.google.com/search?q=Postgresql+do+not+unse+index&oq=Postgresql+do+not+unse+index&aqs=chrome..69i57j0i13i30.4502j0j15&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8

Answer (score 0):

You need to understand the data distribution of your tables.

If your data has low cardinality columns (i.e., columns with a small number of distinct values), then indexing may not provide any significant performance improvements. In such cases, a full table scan may be faster than using an index.

You can read more here - https://medium.com/@atri_iiita/when-indexing-doesnt-help-issues-with-rds-performance-de55560e1176